# ¿Como puedo hacer una busqueda en un Json con PHP?

Tags: php, json

Buenas gente mi proyecto es hacer una web con php pero sacando informacion de un json no de una BD.
Logre hacer el CRUD (el diseño es malisimo pero me gusta mas el back que el front y con JS no me llevo.) hasta con imagenes, tengo un json de productos uno de clientes otro de pedidos, un carrito, puedo mostrar los productos por categorias desde un select, pero no pude implementar una barra de busqueda para que el usuario ponga una palabra y que sea buscada en el archivo json.
El json lo uso como un array en php.

```
<?php

        session_start();
            error_reporting(0);

        $varsesion= $_SESSION['email'];
            if ($varsesion == null || $varsesion ='') {
                header("location:index.php");
            die();

        }
        $cantidadCarrito = 0;

        $json =".json";
        $nombre = $_SESSION['email'];
        $archivoJson = $nombre.$json;

        if(file_exists ( $archivoJson )){
            $str = file_get_contents($archivoJson);
            $ArrayCarrito = json_decode($str, true);
            $cantidadCarrito = count($ArrayCarrito);

        }else{
                
            $cantidadCarrito = 0;
        }
        
        $str = file_get_contents('productos_nogal.json');
        $ArrayProductos = json_decode($str, true);

###Seguidamente generamos un vector o array de claves que guardamos en la variable auxiliar $aux. Si nos fijamos, estamos guardando todas las categoria.####

        foreach ($ArrayProductos as $key => $row) {
            $aux[$key] = $row['categoria'];
        }

########Una vez hemos contruido el array de edades, procedemos a llamar a la función array_multisort() con los 3 parámetros que podemos observar.######

        array_multisort($aux, SORT_ASC, $ArrayProductos);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class=container>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="ListarProductos.php">El Gran Nogal</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav text-center">
    
        <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="ListarPedidosCliente.php" class="btn btn-primary">Mis Pedidos</a>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="carrito.php" class="btn btn-success"> Carrito Items <?php echo $cantidadCarrito; ?></a>
          <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger"> LogOut </a>     
          <li class="nav-item">
          <h6  class="btn btn-warning" ><?php echo $_SESSION['email']; ?></h6>
        
        </li>

    </div>
  </div>
  
    
  
</nav>
<br><br>
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Producto</th>
                    <th>Precio</th>
                    <th colspan="2">
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <?php 
                        

                        $cantidad=count($ArrayProductos);   
                        for($i=0; $i < $cantidad; $i++){
        
                    ?>
            <tr>
                
               
                <td><?php echo $ArrayProductos [$i]['producto']; ?></td>
                <td>$ <?php echo $ArrayProductos [$i]['precio']; ?></td>
                <td><a href="mostrarProducto.php?id=<?php echo $i;?>"> <img src="images/<?php echo $ArrayProductos [$i]['prdImagen']; ?>" 
                            alt="" style="width:100px;height:100px;"></a> </td>
                
            </tr>
            
        <?php
    }
        ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    
</div>

</div>
<!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

y este seria mi json:

```
[{"cod":"1612989376","categoria":"ACEITE","producto":"Aceite Natura 1,5 Litros","precio":"266","prdImagen":"aceite_natura_15ltrs.jpg"},{"cod":"1612995454","categoria":"ACEITE","producto":"Aceite Cocinero 1,5 Litros","precio":"400","prdImagen":"aceite_cocinero_15_ltrs.jpg"},{"cod":1612994231,"categoria":"CELIACOS HARINAS-GALLETITAS-SNACKS ETC","producto":"Galletitas dulces 200 Gramos NATUZEN sin TACC ","precio":"990","prdImagen":"galletitas_Natuze_dukces_sin_Tacc.jpg"},{"cod":"1612989139","categoria":"CEREALES","producto":"SOJA TEXTURIZADA Suelta por Kilo","precio":"500","prdImagen":"soja_texturizada.jpg"},{"cod":"1612992487","categoria":"CEREALES","producto":"Almohaditas 2 de Salvado Granix 4 Kilos","precio":"600","prdImagen":"almohaditas 2 Salvados  Granix 4kilos.jpg"},{"cod":1612993859,"categoria":"COMPLEMENTOS MEDICINALES","producto":"FEGATOl CON MANZANILLA Y VITAMINA C de 500 ml","precio":"900","prdImagen":"FEGATOl CON MANZANILLA Y VITAMINA C de 500 ml.jpg"},{"cod":"1618868612","categoria":"ENCURTIDOS","producto":"Salamn Tandilero Cagnoli Picado Fino 130g.","presentacion":"Unidad x 130 Gramos Aproximadamente","detalle":"PRODUCTO SIN T.AC.C. APTO PARA CELACOS.  Suave y equilibrado sabor, nacido de una armoniosa mezcla ","precio":"299","prdImagen":"salamin tandilero.jpg"},{"cod":1612994406,"categoria":"HARINAS","producto":"Bicarbonato de sodio 10 Kilos","precio":"6800","prdImagen":"Bicarbonato x 10 kilos.jpg"},{"cod":"1612989058","categoria":"HARINAS","producto":"Harina Cauelas 0000 50 Kilos","precio":"1500","prdImagen":"harina_0000_cañuelas_25Kilos.jpg","presentacion":"Notice:  Undefined index: presentacion in \/storage\/ssd3\/939\/16511939\/public_html\/formModificarProducto.php on line 114","detalle":"Notice:  Undefined index: detalle in \/storage\/ssd3\/939\/16511939\/public_html\/formModificarProducto.php on line 120"},{"cod":1612993980,"categoria":"SEMILLAS","producto":"SEMILLA AMARANTO","precio":"350","prdImagen":"SEMILLA AMARANTO 500 gramos.jpg"},{"cod":1612989168,"categoria":"TABACO","producto":"Tabaco Flandria Sauvage 40 Grs","precio":"2000","prdImagen":"tabaco_flandria_sauvage_40Gramos.jpg"},{"cod":1613785199,"categoria":"TE","producto":"Te en saquito Taragui x 50 sobres","precio":"110","prdImagen":"teTaragui.jpg"},{"cod":"1618878884","categoria":"VARIOS","producto":"Cafe La Morenita","presentacion":"1 Kilo","detalle":"Molido Clsico","precio":"989","prdImagen":"7790170901872_02.jpg"},{"cod":"1612989436","categoria":"YERBA","producto":"yerba mate kraus organica 500 gramos","precio":"290","prdImagen":"yerba_mate_kraus_500Grs.jpg"}]
```

He visto muchos videos y archivos, pero no pude lograr hacer esto, que es lo ultimo que me faltaria para terminar y dedicarme al front.

Muchas gracias de antemano por la ayuda.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema en concreto y en qué parte del código?

Comment: No se busca en el archivo Json. Léelo como un array y luego buscas en él.

Comment: Hola, si lo trabajo en forma de array al hacerlo un decode, pero no tengo idea como hacer una barra de busqueda para ese array, no se que metodo usar Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es convertir la cadena json en un array de php utilizando la función *json_decode* (sólo trabaja con string codificados en UTF-8):

Datos de entrada de ejemplo (cadena json):

```
$json = '[{"cod":"1612989376","categoria":"ACEITE","producto":"Aceite Natura 1,5 Litros","precio":"266","prdImagen":"aceite_natura_15ltrs.jpg"},
{"cod":"1612995454","categoria":"ACEITE","producto":"Aceite Cocinero 1,5 Litros","precio":"400","prdImagen":"aceite_cocinero_15_ltrs.jpg"},
{"cod":1612994231,"categoria":"CELIACOS HARINAS-GALLETITAS-SNACKS ETC","producto":"Galletitas dulces 200 Gramos NATUZEN sin TACC ","precio":"990","prdImagen":"galletitas_Natuze_dukces_sin_Tacc.jpg"}]';
```

Código:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Salida ($array):

```
array ( 0 => array ( 'cod' => '1612989376', 'categoria' => 'ACEITE', 'producto' => 'Aceite Natura 1,5 Litros', 'precio' => '266', 'prdImagen' => 'aceite_natura_15ltrs.jpg', ), 1 => array ( 'cod' => '1612995454', 'categoria' => 'ACEITE', 'producto' => 'Aceite Cocinero 1,5 Litros', 'precio' => '400', 'prdImagen' => 'aceite_cocinero_15_ltrs.jpg', ), 2 => array ( 'cod' => 1612994231, 'categoria' => 'CELIACOS HARINAS-GALLETITAS-SNACKS ETC', 'producto' => 'Galletitas dulces 200 Gramos NATUZEN sin TACC ', 'precio' => '990', 'prdImagen' => 'galletitas_Natuze_dukces_sin_Tacc.jpg', ), )
```

Al querer convertir tu json, falla en el siguiente objeto por la ñ de "Cañuelas" y retorna null (recuerda que solo funciona con string codificadas en UTF-8). Tendrás el mismo problema con acentos y caracteres especiales. Una opción es reemplazarlos por su equivalente (Ej: para la ñ sería **&ntilde;** ó **&#241;**):

```
{"cod":"1612989058","categoria":"HARINAS","producto":"Harina Cañuelas 0000 50 Kilos","precio":"1500","prdImagen":"harina_0000_canuelas_25Kilos.jpg","presentacion":"Notice:  Undefined index: presentacion in \/storage\/ssd3\/939\/16511939\/public_html\/formModificarProducto.php on line 114","detalle":"Notice:  Undefined index: detalle in \/storage\/ssd3\/939\/16511939\/public_html\/formModificarProducto.php on line 120"}
```